# Generating primes via composition of polynomials

Tags: number-theory

Is it possible that there is a polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients and an integer $a$ such that the sequence $f(a), f(f(a)), \ldots$ consists only of primes and tends to infinity? Are there any specific polynomials $f$ that are conjectured to have this property?

Comment: @Dietrich: Why must any such polynomial be constant and what does that have to do with Goldbach?

Comment: Goldbach says that a polynomial producing prime values for almost all $n$ is constant (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes). But we need more here. Still I guess that the polynomial must be constant.

Comment: One way of looking at it that might help with an impossibility proof: $f()$ must be irreducible (trivially), but for every prime $p_i=f^{\circ i}(a)$, $0$ must be in the preperiod of the iteration map of $f() \bmod p_i$ but not part of any period - that is, there can be no $k$ with $f^{\circ k}(0)= 0\bmod p_i$.  This can happen for constant polynomials (and by the CRT we can construct a polynomial corresponding to an arbitrary map/function modulo any given prime), but it should be possible to show that for any given polynomial it can't happen once the modulus gets sufficiently large.

Comment: @Steven: Yes, it seems like a strange requirement that $f$ must never return to a multiple of any of its iterates. But I have no intuition about how the modulus being large makes this "no return" policy unlikely.

Comment: @SJR Essentially, because it makes the polynomial 'less arbitrary'.  Keep in mind that for any fixed prime $p$ and any arbitrary function $f():\mathbb{F}_p\to\mathbb{F}_p$, we can find a polynomial $P$ whose values on $\mathbb{F}_p$ match the given $f$.  But for a fixed polynomial, once you choose sufficiently large primes it seems plausible that the behavior 'settles down'.

Answer (score 2):

It is not known whether there exists a univariate polynomial with integer coefficients of degree at least $2$ that assumes an infinite number of values that are prime. See the Bunyakovsky conjecture in this context -  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture. 
The polynomial $f$ with $f^n(a)$ prime would produce infinitely many primes as values. I would believe that $f$ must be constant, but I don't know how difficult it is to prove this. Some of these questions are very hard, as mentioned before.

Comment: Good point! But it might be known that no such polynomial as described in the question can exist. There might be a simple proof of this. Indeed, this is what I suspect.